# WordPress Query display only posts modified today

Tags: php, wordpress, querying

I'm trying to create a query in WordPress that displays only the posts that were *edited* today, *excluding* those *posted* today. I've tried several variations but nothings seem to be working:

```
$today = current_time('Ymd');

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => '10',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'modified',
            'compare' => '>=',
            'value' => $today,
            'type' => 'NUMERIC,'
            )
    ),
    'orderby' => 'modified',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => '1'
);
```

I'm not quite sure what to put in `key`, although that isn't the only problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is unclear. What exactly is the problem with the code you post ? Please edit question and clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get it right, with "displays only the posts that were edited today, excluding those posted today."

I guess you mean display ONLY old published posts modified/edited today.

If that is the case, this might help you:

```
<?php
    // query args
    $args = array(
            'posts_per_page'        => '10',
            'post_type'             => 'post',
            'post_status'           => 'publish',
            'orderby'               => 'modified',
            'order'                 => 'DESC',
            'ignore_sticky_posts'   => '1',
            'caller_get_posts'      => 1
    );

    // query
    $updated = new WP_Query($args);

    // loop
    while($updated->have_posts()) : $updated->the_post(); 

    $today = current_time('Y-m-d'); // current date a.k.a. TODAY
    $pub = get_the_time('Y-m-d', $updated->ID); // date when post was published
    $mod = get_the_modified_time('Y-m-d', $updated->ID); // date when post was last modified

    // if post NOT published today AND was modified today display: 
    if ( $pub !== $today && $mod === $today ) :
?>

<!-- here goes your normal wp game -->
<h1><?php the_title ?></h1>
<span><?php the_date(); ?></span>
<p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>

<?php endif; endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: hallo my friend. yes yours code helped me achieve what needed, just edited it a big. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its not the best solution but you can just do the filter after your query and check if the current date string is inside the post date modified,

e.g.

```
$ar = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => '10',
    'orderby'   => 'modified',
    'order'     => 'DESC',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => '1'
);
$q = new WP_QUery( $ar );
$p = $q->get_posts();
foreach( $p as $a ) {
    $c = current_time( 'Y-m-d' );
    if ( strpos( $a->post_modified, $c ) !== false ) {
        _e( $a->post_title .' '.$a->post_modified. ' - ' . $c. "<br>" );
    }
} 
#echo '<pre>', print_r($p, 1), '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this query to [select all posts either published or modified today](https://seriouswp.com/select-all-wordpress-posts-today/), you could just write this WP_Query to retrieve only the modified ones:

```
   $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'any', // we also want the drafts
        'nopaging'=>true,
        'date_query' => array(
            'column' => 'post_modified',
            'year'  => $day_parsed['year'],
            'month' => $day_parsed['month'],
            'day'   => $day_parsed['day'],
        )
    );

    $query_day_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
```